# What is the right way to create a list from variable and another list?

Tags: python, list

This is the only way i can think of looks like this:

```
var = 1
list = [2, 3, 4]
newList = [var,] + list
```

Is it the right way?

Update: I need to make a new list so insert would not help

Comment: The extra comma isn't needed. You use the extra comma when you declare a tuple `t = (1,)`, that's to differentiate the grouping brackets from the "tupling" brackets. While using square brackets, there is nothing to differentiate: `l = [1]` works fine. One more thing, never declare an element as `list`, because you're losing the `list()` built-in Python function that transforms iterables to list objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you want to avoid adding things to the start of a list in Python: it's O(n) in cost.

If you have to (and often the inefficiency doesn't matter), you can do this:

```
[a] + other_list
```

If you don't mind updating the list you have, you can do this:

```
other_list.insert(0, a)
```

If you can use an iterator rather than a list, you can efficiently use:

```
itertools.chain([a], other_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method is fine (other than the extra comma not needed for a 1-list); people have done it this way for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want to imply by using the `,` after `var` but generally you won;t need it. As you were trying to get other options here is another way to do

```
lst.insert(0,var)
```

If you are not intending to modify the original list you may want to copy it to another list

```
newList=lst[::]
```

and then do the insert

```
lst.insert(0,var)
```

It's a matter of style but I prefer

```
newList=[var]+lst
```

Note****
Generally if you are not intending to modify the original list,

```
newlst = [var] + lst
```

looks cleaner

but in case you want to modify in place your options are

```
lst = [var] + lst
```

or

```
lst.insert(0,var)
```

The later one is preferable because it is more readable and moreover you can use it inside lambda and list-comprehension :-)

Comment: the comma would be needed if you were making a tuple

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand that :-). What I couldn't comprehend in its particular usage with list.

Comment: user is just used to needing to do it for tuples, doesn't realise it is spurious for lists

Answer (score 0):

Use the append method:

```
list.append(var)
```

or insert of you want to place the new element in the beginning:

```
list.insert(0,var)
```

Comment: This modifies the original list, *and* it puts the new value in the wrong place.

Comment: To be fair, won't that put var on the opposite end compared to the OP's code?

Comment: -1: both `append` and `extend` add elements at the end of the list + both modify the original list + `extend(var)` won't work, `extend` works with iterable objects only

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
a_list = []
v = 1
list_to_add = [2, 3, 4]
a_list.append(v)
a_list.extend(list_to_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, go through this **[LIST](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list)**